# How to work with Prepared Statements in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to update an Entry in my mySQL Database. It works fine with here for example:

```
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE user_id = ?";

        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, currUserId);
        System.out.println("Curr User Id: " + currUserId);
        //Execute Query
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

But here I just always get an Error and dont know why.

```
        String sql = "UPDATE entries SET ? = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND id = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, type);
        stmt.setString(2, value);
        stmt.setInt(3, App.connection.currUserId);
        stmt.setInt(4, id);

        int returnValue = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

This is my Error:

````
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username' = 'benNeu' WHERE user_id = 13 AND id = 22' at line 1```
````

Comment: you can't set column names in prepared statements only data

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parameterize object names, so it is not possible to set a column name through a prepared statement. So instead of `SET ? = ?`, you will have to use `SET yourcolumn = ?`, where `yourcolumn` is the right column name.

If that column is dynamic, you will need to concatenate it into your query string (it is recommended you check the column name against a list of allowed column names to prevent SQL injection issues).

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in `SET ? =` is invalid.

Why?

The JDBC driver and the engine can **apply** parameters at a limited number of places in the SQL statement. These correspond to where usually you could see literal values.

You cannot use parameters in the place of a table name, a column name (as you are trying to do in your question), and other SQL clauses in general. Remember parameters are applied, they are not *concatenated* into the SQL statement.

Applying parameters into a SQL statement has two main benefits:

- **Safety**: The query is safe from SQL Injection. If you type a dangerous code segment as a parameter it won't harm the execution; it may fail, but won't delete the whole database because of it.
- **Performance**: The SQL statement will be identical when you call it multiple times with different parameter values. This allows much efficient caching in the engine, and much faster execution.